# Ensemble model predicts negative and extreme values for a non-negative response variable

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, predictive-models, biostatistics, ensemble-learning

I am using SuperLearner() in R to create an ensemble model composed of GLM, GAM, randomForest, gradient boosting model, and multivariate regression spline models. My response variable is tree density, which is a non-negative integer with values generally between 0 - 25.

After training my model I test it in SuperLearner using my holdout test set, which gives me predictions that look normal and fall between the expected range. However, when I then try to expand my predictions and spatially predict across the landscape, using the function raster::predict, I end up with prediction values that range from 0 - 176.
The majority of the predictions do end up in the appropriate range (as you can see in the histogram), but what do I do about the negative and/or extreme predictions? Do I need to void these points N/A, or do I round them up/down?

Similarly in another model for tree basal area, where my true values range between 0 - 2, the predicted values across the landscape range from -2 to 2. With the majority <0!

Why is this happening? Is there a way to avoid it?

FYI - I have not transformed my data in any way. And I am specifying non-negative distributions for my GLM and GAM models (e.g., negative binomial, gamma)[image]

Comment: How many observations do you have? Why such a complex model, maybe start with something simpler, that can actually be understood? Also, tell us more about your predictor variables!

Comment: Thank you for your comment and questions. I chose this selection of models because they are the 5 most common in the literature for answering my research questions. After trying RandomForest only and obtaining poor accuracy, I decided to go for the ensemble and pool these together.  The predictor variables are all climatic (e.g., rain, temperature) and environmental variables (e.g., NDVI, Landcover, canopy cover) that were all obtained from satilite data. Values were all extracted from rasters.

Comment: Please add new information as an edit to the post, and not only in comments! Not everybody reads comments ... then also add even more contextual information, sample size. Since your response variable is necessarily non-negative, maybe try a model for nonnegative data (or simply log-tramsform) A glm (generalized linear model) with log link function could be an idea, or even ordinal regression. Even if you late go for more complex models, a simpler model will be useful as a benchmark. Could you share (a link to) your data?